Is it possible for riverpod in flutter to store an image?
I am using riverpod for state management in flutter. I need to have the user select an image, crop it, temporarily store it before uploading it to the server. I am therefore thinking about storing the image in the riverpod provider that holds other data that should also be uploaded. Can riverpod store an image like this? Is this even a good approach? If not, why? And what would be a better approach?

A riverpod provider should have only one item in State, but it can be a complex object (image data, meta data, etc) using a custom class for the model.

You can refer to this code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gap/gap.dart';
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

import 'buttons.dart';

part 'image_cropper.g.dart';

/// Provider to temporarily hold cropped image.
@riverpod
class CroppedImage extends _$CroppedImage {
  @override
  XFile? build() {
    return null;
  }
}

/// Crop image.
Future<XFile> cropImage(
  BuildContext context,
  XFile imageFile,
) async {
  final croppedFile = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
    sourcePath: imageFile.path,
    aspectRatio: const CropAspectRatio(
      ratioX: 1,
      ratioY: 2,
    ),
    uiSettings: [
      // Android setting.
      AndroidUiSettings(
        toolbarColor: Colors.black,
        toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
        initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio5x4,
        lockAspectRatio: true,
        hideBottomControls: true,
      ),
      // iOS setting.
      IOSUiSettings(
        minimumAspectRatio: 1,
        rotateButtonsHidden: true,
        aspectRatioPickerButtonHidden: true,
      ),
      // Web settings.
      WebUiSettings(
        context: context,
        presentStyle: CropperPresentStyle.page,
        barrierColor: AppColors.blackOverlayColor,
        showZoomer: true,
        enableZoom: true,
        boundary: CroppieBoundary(
          width: context.screenAppWidth.toInt(),
          height: context.screenAppWidth * 5 ~/ 4,
        ),
        viewPort: CroppieViewPort(
          width: (context.screenAppWidth * .9).toInt(),
          height: context.screenAppWidth * .9 * 5 ~/ 4,
        ),
        customRouteBuilder: (cropper, crop, _) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
              return CropperPage(
                cropper: cropper,
                crop: crop,
                cropperContainerWidth: context.screenAppWidth,
                cropperContainerHeight:
                    (context.screenAppWidth * 5 ~/ 4).toDouble(),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
  if (croppedFile == null) {
    throw ImagePickerException.failedCrop();
  }

  return XFile(croppedFile.path);
}

class CropperPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const CropperPage({
    super.key,
    required this.cropper,
    required this.crop,
    required this.cropperContainerWidth,
    required this.cropperContainerHeight,
  });

  final Widget cropper;
  final Future<String?> Function() crop;
  final double cropperContainerWidth;
  final double cropperContainerHeight;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          CommonTextButton(
            text: '提出する',
            onPressed: () async {
              final result = await crop();
              if (context.mounted) {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(result);
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const Gap(16),
          const Text('※画像のトリミングに失敗する場合は縦横比率を調整ください。', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),),
          const Gap(16),
          Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: cropperContainerWidth,
              height: cropperContainerHeight,
              child: cropper,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Use:
final croppedImage = await cropImage(context, image);

